# Upload data into docker container from docker volume

Tags: docker, volume

I wish to create a volume and mount it to a docker container in order to collect some artifacts, and I want to reuse these artifacts into another docker container later on. Can i just mount the same volume to the new container and upload the artifacts? Is there an upload command for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can mount a volume e.g. at `/app/artifacts` then set up your application to place the artifacts on that folder.

```
docker run -d \
-v artifacts-vol:/app/artifacts \
artifact-creator:latest
```

then after that, you can mount the same volume to a separate container and specify on the new container to read the artifacts from the volume location

```
docker run -d \
-v artifacts-vol:/app/artifacts \
artifact-reader:latest
```